# The differential of weighted homogeneous function on sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, spheres

Suppose that $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)$, all $\alpha_j$ are positive rational number. A polynomial $f$ satisfying

$$
f(\lambda^{\alpha_1}x_1,\cdots,\lambda^{\alpha_n}x_n)=\lambda f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)
$$

for all $\lambda>0$, which is called weighted homogeneous polynomial.

Now we focus on $q:=f|_{\mathbb{S}_{\alpha}^{n-1}}$, here

$$
\mathbb{S}_{\alpha}^{n-1}=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:|x|_{\alpha}=\left(\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^{\frac{N}{\alpha_j}}\right)^{\frac{1}{N}}=1\right\}
$$

and $N$ is a positive rational number such that $\frac{N}{\alpha_j}$ are all even integers.

What can we say about the points $x_0\in \mathbb{S}_{\alpha}^{n-1}$ satisfying

$$
q(x_0)=dq|_{x_0}=0.
$$

Here $dq$ is the differential of $q$, can we recognize such points directly from the expression of $f$ instead of computing $dq$?

Comment: I find a characterization of such points and I will give an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $E$ be the set of such points, and
$$
F=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \nabla f(x)=0\}.
$$
Then
$$
E=\left\{\frac{x}{|x|_{\alpha}}:x\in F\backslash\{0\}\right\},
$$
where $|\cdot|_{\alpha}$ is the distance in the definition of $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}_{\alpha}$.

The proof uses Euler's theorem of the homogeneous function.